# Word for a piece of art which makes you tear up?

Tags: word-request, colloquial-language

Is there a word to call *something that makes you cry how good it is* to use in a sentence such as

> This song is a guaranteed [teardropper].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is **tear-jerker**.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tear-jerker)

> If you refer to a play, film, or book as a tear-jerker, you are indicating that it is very sad or sentimental. [informal]

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tearjerker)

> a story, song, play, film, or broadcast that moves or is intended to move its audience to tears